# High CPU usage and traffic on some Cassandra nodes

Tags: linux, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

As stated in the title, we are having a problem with our Cassandra cluster. There are **9 nodes** with a **replication factor of 3** using **NetworkTopologyStrategy**. All in the same DC and Rack. Cassandra version is **3.11.4** (planning to move on 3.11.10). Instances have **4 CPU** and **32 GB RAM**. (planning to move on 8 CPU)

Whenever we try to run repair on our cluster (using Cassandra Reaper on one of our nodes), we lose one node somewhere in the process. We quickly stop the repair, restart Cassandra service on the node and wait for it to join the ring. Therefore we are never able to run repair these days.

I observed the problem and realized that this problem is caused by high CPU usage on some of our nodes *(exactly 3)*. You may see the 1 week interval graph in below. *Ups and downs are caused by the usage of the app. In the mornings, it's very low.*

[image: CPU usage in 1 week]

I compared the running processes on each node and there is nothing extra on the high CPU nodes. I compared the configurations. They are identical. Couldn't find any difference.

I also realized that these nodes are the ones that take most of the traffic. See the 1 week interval graph in below. *Both sent & received bytes.*

[image: Sent & Received bytes in 1 week]

I made some research. I found [this](https://user.cassandra.apache.narkive.com/1dOsCdia/high-cpu-on-nodes) thread and at the end it is recommended to set `dynamic_snitch: false` in Cassandra configuration. I looked at our snitch strategy which is **GossipingPropertyFileSnitch**. In practice, this strategy should work properly but I guess it doesn't.

> The job of a snitch is to provide information about your network topology so that Cassandra can efficiently route requests.

My only observation that could be cause of this issue is there is a file called **cassandra-topology.properties** which is specifically [told to be removed](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/snitch.html?highlight=gossipingpropertyfilesnitch#snitch-classes) if using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

> The rack and datacenter for the local node are defined in cassandra-rackdc.properties and propagated to other nodes via gossip. If cassandra-topology.properties exists, it is used as a fallback, allowing migration from the PropertyFileSnitch.

I did not remove this file as I couldn't find any hard proof that this is causing the issue. If you have any knowledge on this or see any other reason to my problem, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I don't want to be 'that' guy, but, you may find a better response at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: LOL! Thanks, I'll post there too. @vr_driver

Comment: All good. I just figure since this is a programming site, and your problem is for servers, you'll be a better response, and won't have the typical SO answer. lol :D cheers.

Comment: Are you using vnodes.? How are you running repair? What error are you getting when you are loosing nodes (OOM or something else)? Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences tell me some important things about your cluster:

> high CPU usage on some of our nodes (exactly 3).

> I also realized that these nodes are the ones that take most of the traffic.

The obvious point, is that your replication factor (RF) is 3 (most common).  The not-so-obvious, is that your data model is likely keyed on date or some other natural key which results in the same (3?) nodes serving all of the traffic for long periods of time.  Running repair during those high-traffic periods will likely lead to issues.

Some things to try:

- Have a look at the data model, and see if there's a better way to partition the data to distribute traffic over the rest of the cluster.  This is often done with a modeling technique known as "bucketing" (adding another component...usually time based...to the partition key).
- Are the partitions large?  (Check with `nodetool tablehistograms`)  And by "large," like > 10MB?  It could also be that the large partitions are causing the repair operations to fail.  If so, hopefully lowering resource consumption (below) will help.
- Does your cluster sustain high amounts of write throughput?  If so, it may also be dealing with compactions (`nodetool compactionstats`).  You could try lowering compaction throughput (`nodetool setcompactionthroughput`) to free up some resources.  Repair operations can also invoke compactions.
- Likewise, you can also lower streaming throughput (`nodetool setstreamthroughput`) during repairs.  Repairs will take longer to stream data, but if that's what is really tipping-over the node(s), it might be necessary.
- In case you're not already, set up another instance and use [Cassandra Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/) for repairs.  It is so much better than triggering from cron.  Plus, the UI allows for some finely-tuned config which might be necessary here.  It also lets you pause and resume repairs, to pick-up where it leaves off.